# Having a leftrightharpoons with custom length

Tags: arrows

Is it possible to set the length of `\leftrightharpoons` like we do it for `\xrightarrow` for example with `\hspace`?

For example it generates a 8cm arrow:

```
\[ \xrightarrow{\hspace{8cm}} \]
```

But it doesn't work:

```
\[ leftrightharpoons{\hspace{8cm}} \]
```

I'm using `MathJax` to render `LaTeX`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! Would you be able to produce a small [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) ?

Comment: Especially how you control the length of `\xrightarrow`

Comment: Sure, I added the MWE and "M Not WE".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because: mathjax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No idea if this works in `mathjax` (which is btw off-topic on this side), but in normal latex one can use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
    \xrightarrow{\hspace{8cm}}
\]

\[ 
    \xrightleftharpoons{\hspace{8cm}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `graphicx` isn't necessary for this.

Comment: @barbarabeeton My bad! Thanks for your comment! As first approach I tried to cheat with `resizebox`, but that looked horrible :) I guess I forgot to remove the package at that point.

Comment: `mathtools` does some really good things.  this is one of them.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately mathjax doesn't seem to support it, but it's the correct answer anyways.